# How to keep vloopup values even after deleting the vlookup table array?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am working on a excel file which has two sheets:

- Sheet A (uses vlookup functions to obtain values)
- Sheet B (contains the vloopup table array)

The problem is I want to only keep Sheet A in the end but that's not possible because removing the Sheet B causes all the values to become #N/A. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the formulas and paste them as values before the deletion

```
Sub DeleteSheet2WithoutAffectingSheet1
Sheet1.Cells.Copy
Sheet1.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet2.Delete
End Sub
```

Now you can delete the data and the values will remain the same

Comment: That could help but it can be very tedious if it needs to be done every time.. but is there a way to export that data onto a new excel file on button click?

Comment: It needs to be done only once, if you  want,  you can bind this code to button click as well